# Flex container fill viewport height, but minimum height of content

Tags: css, angularjs, sass, flexbox, angular-material

this is basically for a header of a page, the client wants to fill the header so that it fills the viewport completely, but when you shrink the page down vertically, they want the padding above and below the content to remain the same and stop shrinking the header, basically a minimum height of the content + the padding.

I thought this will be simple but I'm stuck, I've tried everything I can think of:

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/suunyz3e/858/

With my demo, if you resize the window, the content shouldn't exceed the 'red' background of it's parent.

I've tried `flex-noshrink` `layout-fill` `min-height:100%`.

I'm sure this is possible but I can't seem to figure it out

Comment: Is it what you wants? [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Muhammad_Usman/suunyz3e/865/)